# Blue dot is not shown on MyLocation using android fused location api

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fusedlocation

I’ve implemented Google map & fuse location API to get current location.
But facing issue like unable to get current location (blue dot) after accepting permission at run time .

This is happened only in fresh installed app, if i kill the app and reopen the app then its works fine.

[image]

am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Without code how can we tell you miss something?

Comment: post your map code

Answer (score 1):

Enable your location

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: this is not the issue, since it is working fine for second time onwards.

Comment: I have the same problem with my emulator. However, it works fine in my real phone.

Answer (score 1):

Add

`map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` in

`onRequestPermissionsResult()` method So it will update the current location after you accept the permission

Comment: it’s perfectly working on second start. so it shouldn’t be issue.

Comment: Second time working because you have granted the permission earlier, keep what is already there just add this one line

Comment: 'in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method' was the key for me